# Timestamp to Bigint (MSSQL) vs. DT_BYTES to DT_I8 (SSIS)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sqldatatypes, ssis-data-types

I'm having issues doing proper data conversion in SSIS when dealing with the "timestamp" data type from SQL Server.

I have a table that im staging from using SSIS. In the source-select in the top of my dataflow task (DFT), it looks something like this:

```
SELECT
     [SourceColumn1Timestamp]       = [SourceColum1Timestamp]
   , [SourceColumn2]               = [SourceColumn2]
   , [SourceColumn3]               = [SourceColumn3]
   , [SourceColumn4]               = [SourceColumn4]

FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

I would like to convert the [SourceColumn1Timestamp] to Bigint, but **inside SSIS** using a data conversion component in the dataflow task. Like this:

[image]

So the input column "timestamp" which is the "DT_BYTES" SSIS data type gets converted into DT_I8.

However the results are completely different from what I expected. And different from the results I would get if i did the conversion in SQL, adjusting the source-select in the DFT to this:

```
SELECT
     [SourceColum1Timestamp]        = [SourceColum1Timestamp]
   , [SourceColumn2]                = [SourceColumn2]
   , [SourceColumn3]                = [SourceColumn3]
   , [SourceColumn4]                = [SourceColumn4]
   , [SourceColum1Timestamp_BIGINT] = CONVERT(BIGINT, [SourceColum1Timestamp]) -- I would like to avoid this
FROM [dbo].[Table1]
```

How come?

Here one row showing the difference between SQL conversion and SSIS:
SQL:
[image]

SSIS:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the same value in SSIS as T-SQL, you'll need to reverse the byte sequence of the binary value in your transformation. That will interpret the binary value as [little-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) sequence (least significant byte first) so the value will be converted to a 64-bit signed integer as expected.

**EDIT:**

I don't know if there's a better way in SSIS but you could reverse the timestamp byte array and convert to a 64-bit integer in a C# script transformation. Here's a function to do that instead of your existing transformation:

```
Int64 convertTimestampToInt64(byte[] timestampBytes)
{
    Array.Reverse(timestampBytes, 0, timestampBytes.Length);
    var timestampInt64 = BitConverter.ToInt64(timestampBytes, 0);
    return timestampInt64;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Any pointers on ways to reverse the byte sequence in SSIS ? And would you trust the results doing the conversion in SSIS one way or the other?

Comment: @DanGuzman i tried your suggestion i gives the same result than Data Conversion. This is weird even implicitly converting and using Derived Column gives a different result then SQL `CAST()`

Comment: @Hadi, what value do you get if you remove the `Reverse`?

Comment: @DanGuzman you're right i was using `Row.Timestamp` *(input column)* instead of `timestampBytes` so when i added the following line `timestampBytes = Row.timestamp;` it works fine. I am really happy that i learned a new thing. Good Luck +1 *(in the first case the Array.Reverse doesn't make sense because Row.timestamp is read only)*

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine#implicit-and-explicit-conversion), I think that timestamp can be implicitly converted into BigInt

[image: Implicit conversion]